# Content Security Policy not working with SHA256

Tags: apache, google-chrome, security, content-security-policy

I'm creating a Content Security Policy on RedHat 6 Apache 2.2 for some html files with JavaScript links to Google.  I have added the following code the virtualhost of the site in `httpd.conf` file.

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: "default-src 'self' https:; script-src 'self' https: https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src inline: 'self' https: 'sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04=' https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https: data: https://www.google-analytics.com; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self' https: https://www.google-analytics.com; child-src 'self'"
```

Cannot get the policy to work unless I use 'unsafe-inline' which I would prefer not to. Latest Chrome browser in developer mode says to add SHA256 hash which I did (see below). Even though I added the recommended SHA256 hash Chrome still asks me to add it????

Am I not handling SHA256 hash correctly?  Any help will be appreciated.

From Chrome developers console.

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src inline: 'self' https:
>   'sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04='
>   https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com". Either
>   the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is discussed in this bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546106
Not totally following what the bug says but it seems the spec only allows sha256 hashes for script and style tags and not for inline scripts and styles. It appears you are going to have to add a 'unsafe-hashed-attributes' attribute to your policy to make it work.

However not totally clear if that is just to fix the script part or also styles, nor if it has been released. It definitely won't have made it to iOS devices that also use WebKit so, for now, I would just allow unsafe-inline for styles.

ORIGINAL ANSWER (before above answer was added but leaving to avoid confusion as comments added below).

I see a few problem:

1. The error mention the Content Security Policy but your example config is the Report Only header. I've seen issues when using both Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only. They should be independent but are not. Might be worth trying without one to see if that's the problem.
2. Your style source includes `inline:` which is not valid syntax AFAIK
3. You include the general `https:` directive and then also specific https sites (`https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com`)

Comment: My guess would be #2. It probably gave up parsing the directive.

Comment: I have tried it with both Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only.  The report only mode allows you to still navigate the site.  The Chrome developers errors are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but no they are not the issue.  To summarize, I have tried to use sha256 soo many different ways and the Chrome response is always the same.  Telling me to add the same sha256 that is already there!!  It's as if I missing some kind of tag, parameter, special quote, etc.

Comment: Can you update your question with the updated header and updated error?

Comment: Sure, here is the updated code.
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: "default-src 'self' script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04=' https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://www.google-analytics.com; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; child-src 'self'"

Comment: And here is the updated Chrome response. 
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04=' https://www.google-analytics.com https://ajax.googleapis.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-j0bVhc2Wj58RJgvcJPevapx5zlVLw6ns6eYzK/hcA04='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, and yes I agree with your recommendation.  Surprised Chrome has such a misleading error message, and they have known about it for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug that is officially tracked with Chromium.
You can find the link here: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41211258?pli=1
It is very annoying indeed. We can't use this security header or feature.
the use of `unsafe-inline` will sledgehammer all the benefits of "**Content Security Policy"**
You can try "`unsafe-hashes`" that is less evil.
I do not think we have a solution for inline java scripts as for now.